# next.js out of the box, comes with error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

Tags: javascript, next.js, compiler-errors

I just installed next.js for my next website, out of the box, I host with "next" and it came with these errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
Object.useContext
file:///C:/Users/sakura/Documents/hosting/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js (1618:21)
Html
..\..\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\next\dist\pages\_document.js (685:105)
renderWithHooks
file:///C:/Users/sakura/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5658:16)
renderIndeterminateComponent
file:///C:/Users/sakura/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5731:15)
renderElement
file:///C:/Users/sakura/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5946:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///C:/Users/sakura/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///C:/Users/sakura/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
finishClassComponent
file:///C:/Users/sakura/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5688:3)
renderClassComponent
file:///C:/Users/sakura/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5696:3)
renderElement
file:///C:/Users/sakura/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5943:7)
```

I'm not sure if this is what usually happens when you first compile this website. Maybe it is.

I expected it to compile the website, which it would show a regular website, and it would show a default page (like what react does) but it returned with an error.

Comment: Same for me. I tried with both javascript and typescript versions.

Surprisingly, I tried to run the website with `npm run dev` and it ran successfully. But it can't with `next dev`.

The `next build` command also gets the error.

Comment: Hello! I opened up the issue on Github originally to have my answer compiled, and it turns out I had next installed globally.

Here's my github issue if you would like to see: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/43091

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had next installed globally.

My issue and discussion is on github:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/43091